# How do I find the median of all prime number(s) within a range?

Tags: c++, loops, primes

For example, I want to find the median of all prime numbers between 9,999 and 100,000. I've done things like find the highest or lowest prime number in arrays but I've never found the median prime number. Any ideas on how to do this? If there are an even number of primes, I would like to find the two closest to the median.

Comment: What do you mean by "middle number"? What is an middle number of prime numbers?

Comment: I assume they mean the median of all primes within the range? So if there were 5 total primes, the 3rd prime by magnitude?

Comment: for example between 1 to 10 prime numbers are 2,3,5,7 so the middle numbers are 3 and 5

Comment: There's no middle if you've got an even number of elements. Which entry does lie between entry 1 and 2?! Otherwise, create a list of all the primes in your range, then halve the number of elements and round down to nearest integer. E.g 3 prime numbers, 3/2 = 1.5 --> 1. The middle element is at index 1.

Comment: @Feathercrown yes the median of all primes sorry I didn't know the term in english :/

Comment: @enhzflep if there were an uneven number of elements then the output would be 2 numbers

Comment: Have you tried the obvious way of finding all prime numbers in that range and then find the median?

See this:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-to-find-prime-numbers-between-given-interval/

Comment: @Lucyn No problem-- I'll edit your question to be more clear for others to answer (Edit: The edit queue is full, I can't do it yet)

Comment: Are you talking about the middle *digits* of a prime number?  The easiest method for finding the middle *digits* of a prime number is to convert the number to a string and find the middle *digits* in the string.

Comment: 1. Use the Sieve of Eratosthenes to find all the prime numbers in the range. 2, Count the prime numbers. 3. Find the median, or the closest of the two middle numbers.